# Jsfiddle errors, a jsfiddle code isn't working elsewhere

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Hi everyone i have this fully working code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Scanu/DhpXN/
But it's not working elsewhere, i think because of the errors that it lists when i click Jslist, how can i fix them?! Thanks in advance and sorry for my english i'm italian :)

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870327/code-works-on-jsfiddle-but-not-on-website) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953488/why-does-the-following-jquery-work-in-jsfiddle-but-not-on-any-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script just executes in JSFiddle after the Page is loaded.
It won't work elsewhere except you place it before your `</body>`-**closing** tag
or you use this script: http://jsfiddle.net/DhpXN/3/